# How to get the data out of Proxy in LWC js?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

My connected callback function :

```
connectedCallback() {
    getData()
       .then((result) => {
        this.infoData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.infos));
        if(this.infoData && this.infoData.length > 0){
          //console.log('this.infoData.length :: ' +this.infoData.data);
          var keys =[];
          for(var key in this.infoData){
            console.log('key,this.infoData[key] :: ' +key,this.infoData[key]);
            if(key,this.infoData[key]["quantity"] == 250){
               //alert('Fetch me the array of the 250 quantity');
               console.log('this.infoData[key]');
            }
          }
        }
      })
       .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error during Callout :' +JSON.stringify(error));

       })
       }
```

and the response looks like this on the console

```
key,this.infoData[key] :: 0
Proxy {}
Handler : wt
membrane :
originalTarget : {price : xxx, price2 : xxx, quantity : xx}
```

I am trying to fetch the array with all the values but I can only get individual values. How can I get the whole array. Please advise.

Comment: Anonymizing non-sensitive data just for the sake of doing so makes it ambiguous as to what you're getting versus what you expect to get. What is your data supposed to look like?

Comment: So, I am displaying the results from my apex rest callout and before showing it on the lighting data table I am looking at the sepcific field i.e quantity when it equals some number and I want to display only the relevant row which contains labels as Price, Price 2 , quantity.